# [WinUI]ArrangeOverride is not being called on invoking its Arrange method

Tags: maui, winui-3, maui-windows

Is there any chance ArrangeOverride notification could get skipped on invoking its Arrange method.

**Code Snippet:**

```cs
class Parent : LayoutPanel
{
..........
    private void method()  --->// any method 
    {
        child.Arrange(new Windows.Foundation.Rect(50,0,100,100));
    }
..........
}

class child : LayoutPanel
{
.......
    protected ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
    }
.......
}
```

While invoking Parent.method(). Despite the fact that the former location is not same (0,0,100,100), child.ArrangeOverride() is not being called.

Comment: Have you tried to call InvalidateArrange

Comment: Did you override the the ArrangeOverride method? And did you check the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.arrange?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: Yes I tried Invalidate @SimonMourier

Comment: Yes I did @LiyunZhang-MSFT